# how do I compare values from javascript array from values in mysql databse with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

so the problem I have is I'm trying to compare dates from JS Array to Mysql database dates. I made booking calendar where you can select available date (let's say from 25.5.2021-28.5.2021) and I'm trying to fix the problem where other user can't book like that (23.5.2021-29.5.2021) because someone else already booked that dates beetween. I've made booking calendar with JQuery Datepicker and it disables theese dates by values in array. That array looks like this: ["23.05.2021","24.05.2021"...]. How do I make sure that it's gonna echo error.

```
function getDatesFromRange($prihod, $odhod, $format = 'Y-m-d') {
    $array = array();
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

    $realEnd = new DateTime($odhod);
    $realEnd->add($interval);

    $period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($prihod), $interval, $realEnd);

    foreach($period as $date) { 
        $array[] = $date->format($format); 
    }
    array_pop($array);

    return $array;
}

$array = getDatesFromRange($prihod, $odhod);
$dolzinaArraya = count($array);

$preveridatum = "SELECT Datumi from zasedenostaljaz";
$sqlprestej ="SELECT COUNT(Datumi) AS stevilo FROM zasedenostaljaz";
$sqlprestej = $db->query($sqlprestej);
$preveripravidatum = $db->query($preveridatum);
$delej = $sqlprestej->fetch_assoc();
$delej = $delej['stevilo'];
echo $delej;
echo "<br>";
$j = 0;
$k = 0;
$l = 0;

$test = 0;
while($k = $preveripravidatum->fetch_array()){
    $test = $k['Datumi'];

    while($l < $delej){
        if($array[$l] == $test){
            $j++;
        }
        $l++;  
    }
    
};

[Database dates[\]\[1\]][1]   

$i = 0;
while ($i < $dolzinaArraya){
    if($j == 0){
        $sqlDatum = "INSERT INTO zasedenostaljaz(Datumi) VALUES('$array[$i]')";
        $ukaz = $db->query($sqlDatum);
        $i++;
    }else{
        echo "error";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: `25.5.2021` is the format of `d-m-Y` and not `Y-m-d` as in the code.